# Different available packages in TensorFlow virtualenv?

Tags: python, tensorflow, linux

I have installed TensorFlow on Linux (Anaconda) by following the documentation which states that one should create and activate a virtual environment `tensorflow`. So far, so good (albeit it is not entirely clear why is this virtual environment is necessary when I want to incorporate TF to my existing env).

But when I activate the tensorflow environment I observe that several packages are unavailable in the new environment while available outside the environment at the same time:

```
$source activate tensorflow
$python

>>>import h5py

... No module named h5py

$source deactivate tensorflow
$python

>>>import h5py
>>>
```

No problem in this case.

I guessed that I should install the missing package in the tensorflow environment as well, but when I try to, I get informed that the package in question has already been installed and nothing happens:

```
$source activate tensorflow
$pip install h5py

Requirement already statisfied ....
```

The same inconsistency occurs with several other packages. What is the problem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't offer any suggestions as to why your virtual environment can't find the packages (I'm not familiar with anaconda). The only thing that comes to mind is a PATH problem.

Perhaps try installing the package with the following command:

```
conda install -n yourenvname [package]
```

or, in your case:

```
conda install -n tensorflow h5py
```

> To install additional packages only to your virtual environment, enter
>   the following command where yourenvname is the name of your
>   environemnt, and [package] is the name of the package you wish to
>   install. Failure to specify “-n yourenvname” will install the package
>   to the root Python installation.

source: https://uoa-eresearch.github.io/eresearch-cookbook/recipe/2014/11/20/conda/

Answer (score 0):

I believe that there might be a conflicting version of python, try to see which python you're using when you're in the virtual environment:

```
which python
```

If the python version you're using is not the one in the conda environment, try setting it:

```
export PATH=path/to/python
```

You can try two more things, first try the conda pip install to see if this works:

```
conda install pip
```

It might be possible that you have two conflicting versions of pip, to see if this is the case try this and set it to the right version with export:

```
which -a pip
```